# Converting OData to an Object

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm making a call to Microsoft Graph to get the manager of a user:

```
/v1.0/name.onmicrosoft.com/users/[email]/manager
```

I'm trying to deserialize the response to a user. The response looks like this.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects/$entity",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "businessPhones": ["+46 xxx xxx xxx"],
    "displayName": "Susanne xxx",
    "givenName": "Susanne",
    "jobTitle": "sales",
    "mail": "Susanne.xxx@xxxx.se",
    "mobilePhone": "+46 xxx xxxx",
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": "Dannstedt",
    "userPrincipalName": "Susanne.xxx@xxx.se"
}
```

I try to serialize it like this:

```
var hasValue = jObject.TryGetValue("userPrincipalName", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, out var value);
if (hasValue)
{
    return value.ToObject<User>();
}
```

userPrincipalName has value but the conversion fails. I'm assuming it is because the User class doesn't have `@odata.context` and `@odata.type`?

What would be the correct way to convert?

Answer (score 3):

No. You are trying to convert a String to a User.

Assuming you have the JSON, you can do the conversion like:

```
string json = ...;
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
```

Assuming a User class like:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserPrincipalName { get; set; }
    //Implement other properties
}
```

Comment: I'd add that you can save yourself a _ton_ of time by using the SDK to handle this: [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet).

Comment: Yes! Using the Graph SDK will save a lot of hassle. Thanks Marc :)

Answer (score 1):

> userPrincipalName has value but the conversion fails. I'm assuming it is because the User class doesn't have @odata.context and @odata.type?

Though juunas has provided the answer, I found that the following code could work as expected on my side. I just traced the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) request without logging in using any account, and simulate the my profile REST API as follows:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "{token:https://graph.microsoft.com/}");
var result = await client.GetAsync("https://proxy.apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com/svc?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fv1.0%2Fme%2F");

var jsonString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var user = jObject.ToObject<User>();
```

Custom User class:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserPrincipalName { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string givenName { get; set; }
    //TODO:
}
```

For your scenario, I assume that you need to check your `User` model, also you could follow the [Microsoft.Graph.User](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph/Models/Generated/User.cs) model provided by Microsoft Graph as Marc LaFleur commented to narrow down this issue. Moreover, you could provide the detailed error message for us to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I am using the Microsoft.Graph.User class. Thats why i thought it should work, but no?

Comment: It's strange. Any exceptions? Have you tried to define your own `User` model? I would recommend you directly use the Microsoft Graph SDK to handle the request for you, you could use `await graphserviceClient.Users[id].Manager.Request().GetAsync()`. Details you could follow [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library Overview](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md).